# $\int_0^x f(t)dt = [f(x)]^2$ and f is never 0

Tags: calculus

Problem says:

Suppose that continuous $f(x)$ is such that:

$$\int_0^x f(t) dt= [f(x)]^2$$

and $f(x)$ is never zero. Then find $f(x)$.

I do the question thinking it say "$f(x)$ is not the zero function"  I find $f(x) = \frac12 x$ as solution.

But, I see from again reading again $f(x)$ can **never** be zero. Now my solution is not correct. $f(0) = 0$ for my solution.

From how I have came to solution I wonder:

Is this possible even to find?

In the way I have solved it seemed this was the only way possible solution.

Comment: You have tried differentiating both sides of your equation and determining $f^\prime(x)$?

Comment: I am also getting $f(x) = x/2 + c$ with $c = 0$. I suspect by $f(x)$ is never zero, one means that $f(x)$ is a non-zero function.

Comment: If you copied the problem correctly, it's not surprising that it's ill-stated, since the equation contains two mistakes -- the free variable and the bound variable shouldn't have the same name $x$, and the $\mathrm d x$ is missing. (If this was a mistake on your part, please take more care in the future; questions often become unintelligible through sloppy copying.)

Comment: I mistyped that.

Comment: I have checked again. It says "f is never zero" exactly. so, this is impossible?

Comment: If one can somehow prove that $f$ is a linear function then one can safely say that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Dilawar: not exactly. It is true however that any line must cross the horizontal axis once.

Comment: My proof shows that f is linear. I took the derivative of both sides. f(x) = mx + b follows from that. But, I do not know if there is another way so that f is NEVER zero. This in Stewarts 6th Calculus book Page 413 problem #3. I assume there must be a solution, but an answer is not given for this problem.

Comment: I have only ever worked with real numbers, except once or twice, mentioning this is omitted in my book's problems. apologies.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for pointing it out. The correct statement is $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$ in $f$ domain if $f$ is linear.

Comment: @tutorcomputer If $f$ is linear than there is no way $f$ can never be zero, given the fact that $f$ is differentiable and hence continuous.

Comment: (Hmm, I suppose I should amend my previous comment to have "any *non-horizontal* line"...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put $x=0$ then you immediately get $f(x) = 0$. I guess what they meant was "$f$ is not identically zero", since $f \equiv 0$ is another solution.

Also, if you follow J.M.'s advice then it's quite helpful to know that $f(x) \neq 0$, at least for $x \neq 0$. You have to assume that $f$ is differentiable, though.

Comment: It suffices to assume that $f$ is continuous, as this implies $\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$ is differentiable.  In fact it suffices to assume $f$ is locally $L_1$, as that implies $\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Expanding on J. M.'s advice.

From $\int_0^x {f(t)dt}  = f^2 (x)$, we get $f(x) = \frac{d}{{dx}}f^2 (x)$ (using that $f$ is continuous). From this, one wants to write $f(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$. In general, however, differentiability of $f^2$ does not imply that of $f$ (consider, for example, the functions $|x-1|$ and $(x-1)^2$, $x \geq 0$; the former is not differentiable at $x=1$), and we are not given that $f$ is differentiable. 
Nevertheless, in our case, for any $x > 0$ we have
$$
f(x) = \frac{d}{{dx}}f^2 (x) = 
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f^2 (x + h) - f^2 (x)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{[f(x + h) + f(x)][f(x + h) - f(x)]}}{h},
$$
leading to 
$$
1 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \bigg[\frac{{f(x + h) + f(x)}}{{f(x)}}\frac{{f(x + h) - f(x)}}{h}\bigg],
$$
where we have used the assumption $f(x)>0$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, it thus follows that
$$
1 = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f(x + h) - f(x)}}{h},
$$
and hence the conclusion that 
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
(The rest is straightforward.)

**Original answer** (see first comment below).

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, then, on the one hand,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ +  } \int_0^x {f(t)dt}  = 0,
$$
and, on the other hand,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ +  } f^2 (x) = f^2 (0).
$$
So the condition $\int_0^x {f(t)dt}  = f^2 (x)$ implies that $f^2 (0) = 0$, hence also $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I now realize that this is what Yuval meant in his first sentence... (so I'll delete this answer later on).

Comment: Rather than deleting it, I'll edit it later on (but not soon), expanding on J. M.'s advice (since there is some delicate point there).